# Список пользователей, имеющих доступ к mySQL

Tags: linux, mysql

Конкретно меня интересует следующая ситуация:
есть пользователь, который имеет права что-либо выполнить в базе данных. Допустим, я захожу в эту БД под этим пользователем с другого IP.

Можно ли узнать, с какого IP был выполнен запрос в БД? Предполагается, что операционная система, **наверное**, регистрирует, кто и через какой порт начал работать с приложениями этой ОС.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос слегка устарел, но, для сообщества, думаю, актуальность потерять не должен был.

Да, у MySQL такая возможность есть.

Есть функция `CONNECTION_ID()`, она возвращает идентификатор подключения. Начиная с MySQL 5.1 в служебной БД `information_schema` есть таблица `PROCESSLIST`, она содержит список подключений с детальной информацией по каждому из них. До 5.1 была команда `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

В таблице `information_schema.PROCESSLIST` есть поле `HOST`. В нем выводится хост и порт на клиенте, через который работает подключение.

То-есть, можно составить SQL-запрос который вернет это поле:

```
SELECT HOST
FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST
WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

Запрос вернет что-то типа `119.195.186.251:51368`

Так как клиентский порт `:51368` для журналирования не несет ни какой ценной информации, его можно отфильтровать с помощью функции `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST, ':', 1)
FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST
WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

В результате получаем `119.195.186.251` - хост клиентского подключения.

Теперь этот запрос можно добавить в любой триггер или хранимую процедуру, чтобы, например, добавить запись в лог-таблицу, или автоматически установить значение поля в какой-то из рабочих таблиц:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST, ':', 1)
FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST
WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()
INTO @host;

INSERT INTO log_table VALUE(..., @host, ...);
```

**PS:** Хочу обратить внимание на то, что все это имеет смысл только в случае, когда подключение к СУБД производится напрямую из клиентского приложения или из консоли. То-есть, для веба этот вариант не подойдет. В веб-приложениях к БД обращается серверный скрипт, а значит запрос всегда будет возвращать хост этого самого сервера.